# Compute the nearby cycles functor for the category of mixed motives

Tags: motivic-cohomology, stable-homotopy-category, vanishing-cycles

I am reading the survey of J. Ayoub, The motivic nearby cycles and the conservation conjecture (see [here](http://user.math.uzh.ch/ayoub/PDF-Files/Leiden.pdf)), in which he introduced the original version motivic nearby cycles (another [note by Illusie](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Eillusie/Illusie-Grothendieck-nearby-cycles12.pdf) is also a good introductory text) for $D^+(-,\Lambda)$ for $\Lambda$ a torsion ring. Let $S$ be the spectrum of a (strictly) henselian DVR (discrete valuation ring). We denote by $j:\eta \to S$ the generic point of $S$ and by $i:s \to S$ the closed point. We fix a separable closure $\overline{\eta}$ of $\eta$. Let $f:X \to S$ be a morphism of finite type.  We form the diagram (by base change)

[image]

The nearby cycles functors $R\Psi_f:D^+(X_{\eta},\Lambda) \to D^+(X_s,\Lambda)$ is defined to be $\overline{i}^*R\overline{j}_*(A_{X_{\eta}})$. Ayoub then tried to define the nearby cycle for some stable homotopical $2$-functors, for instance,

- The motivic stable homotopy category $\mathbf{SH}(-)$ of Morel and Voevodsky;
- The stable category of mixed motives $\mathbf{DM}(-)$ of Voevodsky.

They are all unital monoidal triangulated categories. For rough definitions of these functors, one can consult his note or even his thesis on $\mathbf{SH}(-)$. There is at least one serious problem if one tries to mimic the definition in the case of $D^+(-,\Lambda)$, which is also a stable homotopical $2$-functor in the sense of Ayoub's thesis, is that the resulting functor may not be monoidal. More precisely, if one defines
$$\Phi_f: \mathbf{DM}(X_{\eta}) \longrightarrow \mathbf{DM}(X_s)$$ simply by taking $\Phi_f(A) = \overline{i}^*\overline{j}_*A_{\mid X_{\eta}}$ then $\Phi_f(\mathbb{Z}) \neq \mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the unit of $\mathbf{DM}$ (the image of the base scheme). Let's take $S$ to be the henselization of the affine line over $\mathbb{A}^1_k = \mathrm{Spec}(k[T])$ ($k=\overline{k}$ and $\mathrm{Char}(k)=0$). Ayoub noted that this is an easy computation, one sees that in this case $\overline{S}$ is the limit of $S[T^{1/n}]$ (this is where the hypothesis of being henselian DVR applied), one forms the diagram

[image]

where $e_n$ denotes the $n$-th power map. Then $\Psi_{\mathrm{id}}\mathbb{Z}$ is the colimit of $i^*_n j_{n*}\mathbb{Z}$. Here it comes to the point I do not understand: why $i^*_n j_{n*}\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}(-1)[-1]$ ($(-1)$ means the Tate twist, it makes sense for any stable homotopical $2$-functor via Thom equivalence, and $[-1]$ means the inverse functor of the translation in a triangulated category) and for $n \mid m$, the canonical morphism $i^*_n j_{n*}\mathbb{Z} \to i^*_n j_{n*}\mathbb{Z}$ is given by the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & m/n \\
\end{pmatrix}: \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}(-1)[-1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}(-1)[-1]$$

and hence $\Phi_{\mathrm{id}}\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}(-1)[-1]$. This situation does not appear in etale context because of torsion hypothesis. So I would like to ask whether someone can help me on this computation. Any help is appreciate. Thank you in advance.